How to parse content from HTML-code of a public website using VBA & MSXML2.XMLHTTP?
On this public website, depending on the selected federal state, 30 properties are listed on the right-hand side. If this federal state offers more than 30 properties, then another 30 are listed on the next page.
But when I try to parse the links to the properties with this code, I only get the 30 Objects that are listed on page 1, even if the URL is specified as Page=3:


Sub GetDataFromPublicSite()

Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim GetHref As String
Dim CountItems As Object
Dim x As Long, y As Long
            
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", "https://zvg.com/brandenburg?page=3", False
    .send
     html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
        
Set CountItems = html.querySelectorAll("a")
    
For y = 0 To CountItems.length - 1

    If InStr(html.querySelectorAll("a").Item(y), "brandenburg") Then
    
       GetHref = html.querySelectorAll("a").Item(y).href

    End If

Next

End Sub

Any ideas? I would like to know how I can access the real estate links that are on pages 2,3,4...etc.
Thanks!

A XMLHTTP request is not capable to execute java-script. I guess the (additional) pages are generated by executing js. You can test this by deactivating js in your browser and open the website.

Does this mean there is no way to parse the data?

Yes, you may have to switch to selenium.

Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have no experience with Selenium and would have no idea what the code should look like.

Power Query is a great tool for scraping any kind of data.  This code will get you started.
Sub ZVGQueryNavigate(Url As String)
    Const QueryName As String = "ZVGQuery"
    Dim Query As WorkbookQuery

    ' Check if the query exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Query = ThisWorkbook.Queries(QueryName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Query Is Nothing Then
        ' If query doesn't exist, add it
        AddZVGQuery Url
    Else
        ' Update the query formula
        Query.Formula = GetFVGQueryFormula(Url)
        Query.Refresh
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If
End Sub

Sub AddZVGQuery(Optional Url As String = "https://zvgscout.com/brandenburg?page=3")
    Const QueryName As String = "ZVGQuery"
    Const TableName As String = "ZVGTable"
    
    Dim Formula As String
    Formula = GetFVGQueryFormula(Url)
    
    Dim Destination As Range

    ' Ensure the query does not already exist
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Queries(QueryName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Set destination to the first cell of the active sheet
    Set Destination = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Add the query to the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QueryName, Formula:=Formula

    ' Add a worksheet to display the query output
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' Add the query to the table on the new sheet
    With NewSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & Chr(34) & QueryName & Chr(34) & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=NewSheet.Range("A1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & QueryName & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = TableName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub


Function GetFVGQueryFormula(Url As String) As String
    ' Define the query formula as lines
    Dim Lines(0 To 27) As String
    Lines(0) = "let"
    Lines(1) = "    Source = Web.BrowserContents(" & Chr(34) & Url & Chr(34) & "),"
    Lines(2) = "    #""Extracted Table From Html"" = Html.Table(Source, "
    Lines(3) = "        {"
    Lines(4) = "            {""Case Number"", "".lg\:text-2xl""}, "
    Lines(5) = "            {""Price"", "".text-blue-600""}, "
    Lines(6) = "            {""Property Type"", "".leading-6""}, "
    Lines(7) = "            {""Address"", "".leading-6 + *""}, "
    Lines(8) = "            {""Date & Time"", "".text-1xl:nth-child(5)""}, "
    Lines(9) = "            {""Court"", "".text-1xl *""}, "
    Lines(10) = "            {""Status"", "".top-3""}"
    Lines(11) = "        }, "
    Lines(12) = "        [RowSelector="".group""]"
    Lines(13) = "    ),"
    Lines(14) = "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes("
    Lines(15) = "        #""Extracted Table From Html"","
    Lines(16) = "        {"
    Lines(17) = "            {""Case Number"", type text}, "
    Lines(18) = "            {""Price"", type text}, "
    Lines(19) = "            {""Property Type"", type text}, "
    Lines(20) = "            {""Address"", type text}, "
    Lines(21) = "            {""Date & Time"", type text}, "
    Lines(22) = "            {""Court"", type text}, "
    Lines(23) = "            {""Status"", type text}"
    Lines(24) = "        }"
    Lines(25) = "    )"
    Lines(26) = "in"
    Lines(27) = "    #""Changed Type"""
    GetFVGQueryFormula = Join(Lines, vbNewLine)
End Function


Update Using RegEx
Sub Test_GetZVGScoutLinks()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = GetZVGScoutLinks("https://zvgscout.com/brandenburg?page=3")
    
    With Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data
    End With
    
End Sub

Function GetZVGScoutLinks(Optional URL As String = "https://zvgscout.com/brandenburg?page=3", Optional Prefix As String = "https://zvgscout.com/")
    Dim Text As String
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim Match As Object
    Dim Href As String
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Text = .responseText
    End With

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "<a[^>]*\bclass\s*=\s*""[^""]*(group|hover)[^""]*""[^>]*href\s*=\s*""([^""]+)"""
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    
    Dim Map As New Collection
    ' Find matches
    If RegEx.Test(Text) Then
        Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(Text)
        For Each Match In Matches
            Href = Match.SubMatches(1)
            Map.Add Prefix & Href
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No matching links found on the page!", vbExclamation
    End If
    Set RegEx = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To Map.Count, 1 To 1)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To Map.Count
        Result(n, 1) = Map(n)
    Next
    
    GetZVGScoutLinks = Result
End Function


Extract Links using Power Query
Sub ZVGQueryNavigate(URL As String)
    Const QueryName As String = "ZVGQuery"
    
    Dim Query As WorkbookQuery

    ' Check if the query exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Query = ThisWorkbook.Queries(QueryName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Query Is Nothing Then
        ' If query doesn't exist, add it
        AddZVGQuery URL
    Else
        ' Update the query formula
        Query.Formula = GetFVGQueryFormula(URL)
        Query.Refresh
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    End If
End Sub

Sub AddZVGQuery(Optional URL As String = "https://zvgscout.com/brandenburg?page=3")
    Const QueryName As String = "ZVGQuery"
    Const TableName As String = "ZVGTable"
    
    Dim Formula As String
    Formula = GetFVGQueryFormula(URL)
    
    Dim Destination As Range

    ' Ensure the query does not already exist
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Queries(QueryName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Set destination to the first cell of the active sheet
    Set Destination = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Add the query to the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=QueryName, Formula:=Formula

    ' Add a worksheet to display the query output
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Set NewSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' Add the query to the table on the new sheet
    With NewSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & Chr(34) & QueryName & Chr(34) & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=NewSheet.Range("A1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & QueryName & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = TableName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub


Function GetFVGQueryFormula(URL As String) As String
    ' Define the query formula as lines
    Dim Lines(0 To 9) As String
    Lines(0) = "let"
    Lines(1) = "    Source = Web.BrowserContents(" & Chr(34) & URL & Chr(34) & "),"
    Lines(2) = "    #""Extracted Links From Html"" = Html.Table("
    Lines(3) = "        Source, "
    Lines(4) = "        {{""Links"", ""a.group"", each [Attributes][href]}}, "
    Lines(5) = "        [RowSelector="".group""]"
    Lines(6) = "    ),"
    Lines(7) = "    #""Removed Nulls"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Extracted Links From Html"", each [Links] <> null)"
    Lines(8) = "in"
    Lines(9) = "    #""Removed Nulls"""
    GetFVGQueryFormula = Join(Lines, vbNewLine)
End Function


Dear TinMan, I am honored that you have taken the time to look into my problem and I sincerely thank you for this solution. The data on the 2nd page is parsed correctly, but how do I determine the most important thing what I actually need, namely the link to each object? These links are listed in site HTML as HREF. Just attached a screenshot of it under my question. I have only ever worked with selectors to access content, so I don't know how to integrate the links (div a href) into the "GetFVGQueryFormula" function?

@Jasco I updated my answer using RegEx to extract the links.

Many thanks for the answer, unfortunately the result of this code is the same problem I'm struggling with all the time: it lists the properties of the FIRST page (Page=1), not those of Page3, although the URL is specified as Page=3 :-(

@Jasco you could try a Python solution.  The bottom line is that the website is terrible.

I could figure out this Excel code for the HREFS >>> = Html.Table(Source, {{"Column ""1""", ".group", each [Attributes][href]?}}). How could I replace the row in your code LINE(10) : Status with this one?

@Jasco I managed to extract the links using Power Query.
